# How many states in this ‘air cargo’ state planning example?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

In the AI textbook I’m reading, there is a state planning example. Part of the example is:

> “There are 10 airports and 50 planes. Each plane can be at one of 10
>   airports, so there are 50^10 states.”

I don’t understand. Shouldn’t there be **10^50 states,** since there are 50 planes, and ten choices for the airport each plane is located at?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This question actually would find better answers at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This example is from the textbook Artificial Intelligence A Modern Approach, which I thought was a popular CS textbook. Is this actually an error in the textbook and not something I’m misunderstanding? Are states counted differently in state planning problems? Should I post a picture of the page?

Comment: I believe you without a picture ..

Comment: It would be an interesting mental gymnastics to arrive at 10^50 by adding the possible states where 10(all) planes are in one airport plus the in between cases plus the case where all 10 planes are in different airports.

Comment: @Adder, there are 45 connections between airports, plus 10 airports = 55 possible locations for the 50 planes. Assuming a plane can be at an airport, or in transit between 2 airports, the number of states in that case, would be (55^50 or ~ 10^88)